# 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: vb.net

I have a data grid view , I want to export to Excel.
I want to export only the Visible columns in the data grid view.

But I keep getting this error.

```
 Private Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim ExcelWorkBk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ExcelWorkSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    ExcelApp = New Excel.Application
    ExcelWorkBk = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add()
    ExcelWorkSht = ExcelWorkBk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim columnsCount As Integer = DGVinfo3.Columns.Count
      For i = 0 To DGVinfo3.RowCount - 1
        If DGVinfo3.Columns(i).Visible = True Then
            For j = 0 To DGVinfo3.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 0 To DGVinfo3.Columns.Count + 1
                    If DGVinfo3.Columns(k).Visible = True Then
                        ExcelWorkSht.Cells(1, k) = DGVinfo3.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                        ExcelWorkSht.Cells(1, k).Font.Bold = True
                        ExcelWorkSht.Cells(1, k).interior.color = RGB(192, 203, 219)
                        ExcelWorkSht.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DGVinfo3(j, i).Value
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

I keep getting this error:

> System. Argument Out Of Range Exception: 'Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Here is where I get the Error:

```
ExcelWorkSht.Cells(1, k) = DGVinfo3.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
```

Comment: `For k As Integer = 0 To DGVinfo3.Columns.Count + 1` did you meant to have a `-1`  instead of the `+1` ?

Comment: @litelite Still same problem still giving error

Comment: DGVinfo3.Columns.Count + 1 and then later on (i + 1, j + 1). What are you trying to accomplish? Also (k-1) when k is 0??

Comment: `ExcelWorkSht.Cells(1, k) = DGVinfo3.Columns(k - 1)` on the first loop, `k` will be 0 so `k-1` will be -1 which is invalid

Comment: @n8wrl Im trying to export the datagridview information to excel, without hidden Columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop the rows and inside that loop each column. Also because the hidden columns won't be exported to Excel, it's probably best to keep track of the Excel columns in a separate variable:

```
  Dim xlColumn As Integer

  For i = 0 To DGVinfo3.RowCount - 1
        xlColumn = 0
        For j = 0 To DGVinfo3.ColumnCount - 1
                If DGVinfo3.Columns(j).Visible = True Then
                    xlColumn += 1
                    If i = 0 Then 
                       'You only need to set the column headers for the first row
                       ExcelWorkSht.Cells(1, xlColumn) = DGVinfo3.Columns(j).HeaderText
                       ExcelWorkSht.Cells(1, xlColumn).Font.Bold = True
                       ExcelWorkSht.Cells(1, xlColumn).interior.color = RGB(192, 203, 219)
                    End If
                    'i + 2 because the header is row 1
                    ExcelWorkSht.Cells(i + 2, xlColumn) = DGVinfo3(i, j).Value
                End If
        Next
  Next
```